# Beta Calendar events documentation scopes

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

When I look into the beta reference [create a event](http://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/beta/api/user_post_events) the scopes required section is empty. Is this a documentation issue or can I use this api without scopes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a documentation issue. I created https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/142 for it. The required scope is Calendars.ReadWrite.